# Parsing Chess .pgn files

Tags: c#, c++

I am developing a chess engine and I want to parse chess .pgn files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) to be able to extract games and the moves of the players in each extracted game and store it in SQL DataBase. when I tried to parse .pgn file in C# or C++, I could not deal with it. So I need a help for doing this.

Thank u in advance

Comment: _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."_ - from [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Can you give a link to an example .png that you would like to pars, a give more details on to what parsing an image means to you?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić It's pgn, not png.

Comment: It is not .png file, it is .pgn file :) it is a chess file containing information about chess games such as players, date of game, moves, etc.
here is a link to explain more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation

Comment: Check the references at your link for some good information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#References, specifically the parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is One.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgnlib/

its a free software too

http://pgnlib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thank you very much, its a very good library

Comment: May be, if you mark it as answer the question may go out of onhold state and others can use this library too.

Comment: I need another help please :) I am trying to run the examples exist in the library such as example1. when I wrote the code exactly like the example I had this error (Unable to start program'E:Master\Games\BoardGames\Chess\C++LibraryForPGNFiles\pgnlib0.2.2\newTry\Game\Debug\Game.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified.)   
I think the problem is in this line (pgn::GameCollection games;)
Can you help me?

Comment: A qucik comment. Isn't it should be "E:\Master" instead of "E:Master"

Comment: Yes it is "E:\Master" not "E:Master"

Comment: I need help using the library .... when trying to run Example_5 and Example_3, errors appears. In example_5 the error is string subscript outside range. and for Example_3 the error is vector iterator outside range!
I need help to solve these errors please as I need to use this library urgently.